# Trouble with Knockout Mapping Create/Update

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

I am trying to map data so that elements only get re-rendered when values have actually changed.

```
{
    Apps : [
        {
            "Categories" : [{
                    "Name" : "#Some,#More,#Tags,#For,#Measure"
                }
            ],
            "Concentrator" : "",
            "Health" : 1,
            "Id" : 2648,
            "Ip" : "1.1.1.1",
            "IsDisabled" : true,
            "IsObsolete" : false,
            "Name" : "",
            "Path" : "...",
            "SvcUrl" : "http://1.1.1.1",
            "TimeStamp" : "\/Date(1463015444163)\/",
            "Type" : "...",
            "Version" : "1.0.0.0"
        }
        ...
    ]
    ...
}

var ViewModel = function() {
    self.Apps = ko.observableArray([]);
}

var myModel = new ViewModel();

var map = {
    'Apps': {
        create: function (options) {
            return new AppModel(options.data);
        },

        key: function(data) { return ko.utils.unwrapObservable(data.Id); }
    }
}

var AppModel = function(data){
    data.Categories = data.Categories[0].Name.split(',');
    ko.mapping.fromJS(data, { }, this);
    return this;
}

function UpdateViewModel() {
    return api.getDashboard().done(function (data) {
        ko.mapping.fromJS(data, map, myModel);
    });
}

loopMe(UpdateViewModel, 5000);

function loopMe(func, time) {
    //Immediate run, once finished we set a timeout and run loopMe again
    func().always(function () {
        setTimeout(function () { loopMe(func, time); }, time);
    });
}

<script type="tmpl" id="App-template">
    <div>
        <!-- ko foreach: Categories -->
        <span class="btn btn-default btn-xs" data-bind="text:$data"></span>
        <!-- /ko -->
    </div>
</script>
```

On the first run of UpdateViewModel I will see 5 spans as expected. On the second call, receiving the same data, it gets updated to a single span that says [Object object] which is because it still thinks Categories is an array of objects instead of an array of strings.

Everything seems fixed if I change 'create' to 'update' in my map, however it seems that the spans are then re-rendered every time regardless if data changed or not.

Can anyone lend me a hand in the direction I need to go so that I can

1. adjust the Categories array from objects to strings
2. Only re-render/render changed/new items

Here is a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Zholen/Lu743qds/1/) showing the behavior

Comment: I wanted to help, so I started by [creating a repro based off your code](https://jsfiddle.net/Lu743qds/), but found that the jsfiddle doesn't show any problem at all? (No "[Object object]" trouble, no re-rendering of categories, nothing.) Can you either explain where my repro went wrong, or update your code to be an mcve?

Comment: @Jeroen Thanks for starting a fiddle for me. I have edited where you started and replicated the behavior I am seeing. I added a counter that just switched the fakeData, but with the same exact data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with these lines:

```
var AppModel = function(data){
    data.Categories = data.Categories[0].Name.split(','); // <-- mainly this one
    ko.mapping.fromJS(data, { }, this);
    return this;
}
```

There's two problems:

1. You mutate the `data` object which (at least in our repro) mutates the original object that `data` references to. So first time one of the fakeData objects is passed in, that one is mutated in place, and will forever be "fixed".
2. You mutate it in the `AppModel` *constructor* function, which is only called the first time. According to your `key` function, the second time the constructor should *not* be called, but instead ko-mapping should leave the original object and mutate it in place. But it will do so with a "wrongly" formatted `data.Categories` property.

The correct fix seems to me to be in your data layer, which we have mocked in the repro, so it makes little sense for my answer to show you how.

Another more hacky way to do this would be to have an `update` method in your mapping like so:

```
update: function(options) {
  if (!!options.data.Categories[0].Name) {
    options.data.Categories = options.data.Categories[0].Name.split(',');
  }
  return options.data;
},
```

When it encounters an "unmodified" data object it'll do the same mutation. See [this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ep3ekovy/) for that solution in action.

Comment: Thanks for getting me there. I knew i was doing something incorrect with the map. I guess i just wasn't putting 2 and 2 together. I appreciate your time. I'll be fixing this via the data layer as you suggest.